# Design of attenuators in microwave systems

Tags: microwave, attenuator

A thin dielectric strip is coated with a resistive film to attenuate microwave signals. However, the dielectric strip is tapered at both ends to reduce reflections. Why does the dielectric strip even reflect the microwave signal? Is this because of impedance mismatch? And if so, why does tapering reduce the reflection?[image: Resistive Card in attenuators]

Comment: we'll definitely need to see your specific example. This sounds like a very specific device, and we can't tell you anything about it without knowing exactly what you're referring to.

Comment: this sounds like a card in a waveguide. It's different for coaxial or microstrip structures. We need a picture of the setup.

Comment: Post updated with image. @Neil_UK, yes, they do talk about resistive cards or dielectric cards in this chapter, but it isn't really explained anywhere

Comment: I just found this statement in a book. "The dielectric plates are tapered through a length of quarter wavelength at both ends for reducing reflection due to discontinuity". This is kinda the impedance mismatch they are talking about right? Although this answer is fine, I still don't know why tapering helps. Does the gradual change in impedance reduce reflection? If so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such microwave attenuators are very common, and work by absorbing the Microwave energy into a lossy material which then dissipates this energy as heat.

However, as you might have learnt from EM theory, introducing any material discontinuity causes reflections because of the impedance mismatch at the discontinuity. This means not all the energy is absorbed by this lossy material thereby reducing its effectiveness as an attenuator.

The taper here is performing the role of an broadband impedance matching section. You might be familiar with the Quarter Wave Transformer, i.e a section of line that performs **narrow band** impedance matching. Now intuitively, if you chain a series of such sections you can expect a wider bandwidth of the impedance match. The taper is simply an extreme example of this where the impedance matching sections is essentially just a section of line where the impedance varies continuously.

Interestingly, the shape of the taper defines the **frequency response of the Input Reflection Coefficient**! So this shape is not arbitrary, and is rather carefully chosen to achieve a certain frequency variation of the Input Reflection Coefficient (looking into the start of the taper).

Do you see the strong similarity between this exercise and that of the more familiar filter synthesis where we choose filter coefficients (hence shape of impulse response!) to attain a certain frequency response such as Butterworth, Chebyshev etc?. By analogy all of this also applies to taper synthesis where we instead shape the taper to attain a certain shape of \$\Gamma_I(\omega)\$!

If you would like to know more look for:
1) Theory of Small Reflections
2) Tapered Transmission Lines

If you are instead interested in the maths behind this, leave a comment and I shall try and put together a quick derivation as an edit :)

Comment: Thanks. I would really appreciate the math behind this.

Comment: @PradyothShandilya for a lot of practical devices, the math is "my gigantic finite elements analysis said this shape is pretty good, given the material's constraints". For the basics you need to understand before you can really do a simulation that *means* something, read Pozar's microwave engineering page 1 to end. This is complicated stuff.

Comment: @Marcus, thanks. I've started out with Joseph White's High Frequency Analysis. I'll check out Pozar too

Comment: Haven't read White, Pozar kind of is the "classic" in that field, I just don't find the edition I had to study with overly satisfying in notation, but that's probably not even a choice Pozar had.